# Permanent redirection in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect below URL

http://www.abc.com/preview.asp?type=content&id=237#logo

to

http://www.abc.com/preview.aspx#logo

Any idea about rewrite rules like :

```
<rule name="Home Document" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^visiting.aspx$"  />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^utm_source=invite%2B&amp;utm_medium=Email%2B&amp;utm_campaign=exhibitor$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com/visiting.aspx" appendQueryString="false"/>
            </rule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `redirectType="Permanent"` to generate a 301 status code:

```
<rule name="Home Document" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^visiting.aspx$"  />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^utm_source=invite%2B&amp;utm_medium=Email%2B&amp;utm_campaign=exhibitor$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com/visiting.aspx" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
 </rule>
```

Comment: Above rule is working for me. But I need to check # in condition like : http://www.abc.com/preview.asp?type=content&id=237#logo and redirect this link to http://www.abc.com/preview.aspx#logo